# Laptop with a GTX 1060 or up, supporting 64 GB of RAM, Windows 7

Tags: laptop

I am looking for a laptop with the following specifications:

- has an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060, 1070, or 1080
- supports 64 GB of RAM (it doesn't have to come with 64 GB of RAM, but I should be able to upgrade to 64 GB)
- Microsoft Windows 7 can be installed on it (it doesn't have to be "officially" supported).

Regarding the price:

- Budget: up to around 3kUSD (no hard limit)
- Preferred country of purchase: United States

---

PS: I need Windows 7, please don't add comment about Windows 10 or virtual machines. I've already other computers running on Windows 10.

Comment: Is Price an issue, or 20K is also fine? If not say your max price range.

Comment: @YisroelTech up to around 3kUSD

Answer (score 1):

Although there cannot be a single answer, there are a lot of devices from different gaming manufacturers that meet your criteria, but I will point you to this [**MSI GT75VR TITAN PRO-215**](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B079CD4QHN)

I think it ticks all the boxes and more benefits:

- Has the Nvidia 1080 (the best of the 3)
- Comes already with a good 64GB or RAM
- The quad-core i7 is not bad...although you have not mentioned CPU specifically
- Has a fast SSD for a bonus... but still enough storage in the secondary HDD
- It comes with Windows 10 (like every recent device...) but there is no reason why you would not be able to install Windows 7 on it. Windows Updates will not work out-of-the-box in Windows 7 (because it is a 7th gen Intel CPU) but you can use something like [wufuc](https://github.com/zeffy/wufuc) to get around it.

Comment: Thanks. "there is no reason why you would not be able to install Windows 7 on it. " I am afraid that some component may not have any Windows 7 compatible driver. The ability to run on Windows 7 is the most difficult requirement to satisfy, as the information is difficult to find :(

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I highly doubt that should be a real concern. The GPU and CPU work, and that's the main, all it others you can really play around with the drivers and get to work.